# Ethernet is Unstable after Upgrade Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, upgrade, 16.04, ethernet

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and everything was running perfectly until yesterday I chose to run an `apt-get upgrade`.

Now the Ethernet is unstable. Pages don't load and it shows the “Internet is Unavailable” error frequently.

The only temporary fix is *Disable Networking* and then re enable it.

1. output of `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Ethernet`:

   ```
   01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros AR8162 Fast Ethernet [1969:1090] (rev 10)
     Subsystem: Lenovo AR8162 Fast Ethernet [17aa:3979]
     Kernel driver in use: alx
     Kernel modules: alx
   ```
2. [`/var/log/apt/history.log`](http://pastebin.com/KFg6QfFA) ([redacted for better readability](//paste.ubuntu.com/22150291/))
3. [result of the wireless script](http://pastebin.com/gjUeHKBd)

P.S.: Please mention in comments about any commands that I need to run so that I can paste it's output here.

Comment: ping your ip and check if packets are dropping. also set your IP since its ethernet.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Thanks for the Suggestion . Added the output

Comment: Updated question with requested outputs. Thanks

Comment: There was a major upgrade of the `network-manager` and its affiliated `libnm-*` packages that may cause issues. Could you please try to revert to the previous versions with `sudo apt-get install libnm-glib-vpn1=1.1.93-0ubuntu4 libnm-glib4=1.1.93-0ubuntu4 libnm-gtk-common=1.1.93-1ubuntu1 libnm-gtk0=1.1.93-1ubuntu1 libnm-util2=1.1.93-0ubuntu4 network-manager-gnome=1.1.93-1ubuntu1 network-manager=1.1.93-0ubuntu4` and see how it goes? If that helps, I'll write an answer that includes how avoid the upgrade of those packages to their newer counterparts.