# Network unstable in 16.04LTS - Google apps not usable

Tags: networking

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and since last week, my network connection has become totally unstable on my 2 Ubuntu computers. I cannot recall a specific event of changing anything in the OS. Below the results with various computers & OSs on the same network

```
+---------------------+-----------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+-----------------+-------------+
|                     |                  Computer A                 |        Computer B         | Computers C & D | Smartphones |
+---------------------+-----------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+-----------------+-------------+
|                     | Windows 7       | Ubuntu                    | Ubuntu                    | Windows 7 & 10  | Android     |
|                     | Ethernet & Wifi | Ethernet & Wifi           | Wifi                      | Wifi            | Wifi        |
+---------------------+-----------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+-----------------+-------------+
| NAS file browsing   | OK              | Unstable                  | Unstable                  |                 |             |
| on local network    |                 |                           |                           |                 |             |
+---------------------+-----------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+-----------------+-------------+
| Internet,           | OK              | OK                        | OK                        | OK              | OK          |
| excl. Google Apps   |                 |                           |                           |                 |             |
+---------------------+-----------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+-----------------+-------------+
| Google Apps         | OK              | NOT USABLE                | NOT USABLE                | OK              | OK          |
| Sheets, drive, docs |                 | CONNECTION OFTEN          | CONNECTION OFTEN          |                 |             |
|                     |                 | LOST FOR 10 MINUTES       | LOST FOR 10 MINUTES       |                 |             |
|                     |                 | Slow the rest of the time | Slow the rest of the time |                 |             |
+---------------------+-----------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+-----------------+-------------+
```

ping performances with several websites (I am in France)
(on my Windows computers : lower loss on the google.com servers !!)

```
--- google.com ping statistics ---

27 packets transmitted, 19 received, 29% packet loss, time 26070ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 8.056/9.102/12.221/1.242 ms    

--- drive.google.com ping statistics ---

17 packets transmitted, 11 received, 35% packet loss, time 16055ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 8.158/9.721/11.676/1.224 ms

--- free.fr ping statistics ---

12 packets transmitted, 12 received, 0% packet loss, time 11019ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 8.486/8.713/8.912/0.171 ms

--- yahoo.com ping statistics ---

14 packets transmitted, 14 received, 0% packet loss, time 17150ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 115.742/118.006/125.620/2.512 ms
```

traceroute results *(01/10/2016 edit)*

```
1  192.168.1.254 (192.168.1.254)  0.424 ms  0.419 ms  0.417 ms
2  chn60-1-82-233-48-254.fbx.proxad.net (82.233.48.254)  4.564 ms  5.177 ms  5.377 ms
3  213.228.28.126 (213.228.28.126)  6.029 ms  6.435 ms  6.434 ms
4  p11-crs16-1-be1121.intf.routers.proxad.net (194.149.163.133)  16.336 ms  16.536 ms  16.535 ms
5  cbv-crs8-1.intf.routers.proxad.net (78.254.249.102)  10.036 ms  10.273 ms  10.677 ms
6  72.14.211.26 (72.14.211.26)  10.467 ms  8.947 ms  9.146 ms
7  72.14.239.205 (72.14.239.205)  9.347 ms  9.927 ms  9.553 ms
8  209.85.143.243 (209.85.143.243)  9.097 ms  8.830 ms  9.252 ms
9  par10s22-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.208.238)  9.020 ms  9.498 ms  9.701 ms
```

I have pinged every one of the servers.

. 0% packet loss until server #7

. 100% packet loss on server #8 (both Linux and Windows)

. ~30% packet loss on server #9 (Linux) lower packet loss Windows

**Despite same packet loss on the 2 systems, Google Apps work perfectly on Windows, not on Ubuntu.**

Output of lshw:

```
sudo lshw -class network

  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       produit: Killer E220x Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       fabriquant: Qualcomm Atheros
       identifiant matériel: 0
       information bus: pci@0000:02:00.0
       nom logique: eth0
       version: 13
       numéro de série: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
       taille: 1Gbit/s
       capacité: 1Gbit/s
       bits: 64 bits
       horloge: 33MHz
       fonctionnalités: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx duplex=full ip=192.168.1.xx latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       ressources: irq:33 mémoire:f7d00000-f7d3ffff portE/S:e000(taille=128)
  *-network DÉSACTIVÉ
       description: Interface réseau sans fil
       produit: Wireless 7260
       fabriquant: Intel Corporation
       identifiant matériel: 0
       information bus: pci@0000:03:00.0
       nom logique: wlan0
       version: 6b
       numéro de série: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
       bits: 64 bits
       horloge: 33MHz
       fonctionnalités: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.4.0-38-generic firmware=16.242414.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       ressources: irq:30 mémoire:f7c00000-f7c01fff
```

I have not changed anything in the configuration since then. Tried the approach at [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/806033/ethernet-is-unstable-after-upgrade-ubuntu-16-04?newreg=4c96f71e093e4ce9923ea853c014a3aa) but with no success (could not install the proposed versions - error message)

Ubuntu is configured to update automatically.

Please advise which tests to do / fixes to bring.

I use Google Apps in my job, and it has become impossible to use my main computer for this reason. I believe Google Apps requires particularly stable connections, which is not the case anymore.

Thank you,
Ed

Comment: Did you update at all, try to reinstall any drivers, etc.? What wireless cards do these have? Type this command: "lshw -class network", and edit your post.

Comment: Hello, new info is added. I have been researching forums on packet loss with no success. Tried to change ring buffer size with eth0, but received an error message. Please help !! I cannot see any other solution than trying another distro now.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the symptoms, maybe no the root cause.

I have entirely wiped Google Chrome (including profiles, settings, etc), and then re-installed it. Problem with Google Apps gone.

However, I still get a poorer ping on Ubuntu than on Windows. I have no explanation / solution for that.